# Codeigniter 404 page not found, how to setup

Tags: codeigniter

I have uploaded my codeigniter project in the server but apart from index page other pages are not loading, only giving the 404 page not found error.

I have set all the configurations and created the files correctly but still this error is frustrating me.

.htaccess file --

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

config.php --

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.doupnow.com/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

routes.php --

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['home'] = 'home/index';
$route['faq'] = 'home/faq';
$route['privacy-policy'] = 'home/policy';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

My Controller --
Home.php

```
    public function index()
{
    $result['data']=$this->Home_Model->video_url();
    $result['list']=$this->Home_Model->video_list();
    $result['list2']=$this->Home_Model->funny_video();
    $result['list3']=$this->Home_Model->funny_audio();
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('home_page', $result);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}

public function faq()
{
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('help');
    $this->load->view('footer');
}

public function policy()
{
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('privacy_policy');
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

My Modal --

```
Home_Model.php
```

My Views --

```
home_page.php
help.php
privacy_policy.php
header.php
footer.php
```

Now when i am browsing www.doupnow.com, its going to the index page. But when i click the FAQ or POLICY link [http://doupnow.com/faq], its showing 404 page not found error. Kindly assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OMG everything was correct only. There was just 1 setting to be done at the server side.
Since my web server is cent os so i just updated the AllowOverride option from None to All in the httpd conf file. And now everything working properly.

Thanks for your support guys.

Answer (score 1):

check your urls working if change it like 
`http://www.doupnow.com/index.php/home/faq` if it working then 
replace your .htaccess code with this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

after this it should work !

I checked with this url `http://doupnow.com/index.php/home/faq` its working. Link you given  [http://doupnow.com/faq] its wrong, Link should be `base_url/controller/method` In your case

`http://doupnow.com/ = 'base_url`

`home = controller`

`faq = method`

`final url = 'http://doupnow.com/home/faq`

Comment: changed the .htaccess file. But its not working. Is my routes.php file is correct?

Comment: what is your .htaccess file location ? it should be in
`public_html/doupnow.com/.htaccess`

Comment: doupnow.com/index.php/home/faq  its opening correctly but when i click on FAQ hyperlink then its taking me to http://doupnow.com/faq with 404 error and if i change the url as http://doupnow.com/home/faq then also 404 is coming

Comment: public_html/doupnow.com/.htaccess its there only

Comment: `<li><a href="<?= base_url() ?>faq">FAQ</a></li>`

Comment: main problem is your .htaccess only ! nothing else

Comment: changed the .htaccess as per your code but then also not working. What may be the issue not getting it. :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49731783/codeigniter-project-loads-nothing-on-the-localhost-browser/49732921#49732921 Refer my answer here. It may help you.

Comment: @Rishi   checked with your answer, but same issue.

Comment: Worked like charm

Answer (score 0):

You should change every `Href` form `href="YOUR-METHOD-NAME"` to `href="<?php echo base_url('YOUR-METHOD-NAME');"` or `href="<?php echo base_url();YOUR-METHOD-NAME"`

Comment: then try like  `href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>YOUR-CONTROLLER / YOUR-METHOD-NAME"`

Comment: Its going to "http://doupnow.com/home/faq" and display the error message "The requested URL /home/faq was not found on this server."

Comment: then sadly, there are problems with `.htaccess` , and this is the area i cant assist.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your URL properly as your server is not working without index.php, rewrite_module is not turned on. 
write your url with site_url() function.
For example:

```
site_url('faq');
```

Comment: after changing as per your suggestion, on clicking the hyperlink its leading to "http://doupnow.com/faq" page where its showing 404 not found error